# How to pass a rule attributes value to its dependencies?

Tags: c++, compilation, cross-compiling, bazel, bazel-rules

I'm implementing a custom toolchain in Bazel, and I'd like to pass the value of an attribute to the deps of the target.

***Example***: Here, I want to access the `includes` attribute value in `TARGET_A`.
:

`BUILD`:

```
object_file(
    name = "TARGET_A",
    srcs = ["path/to/source.c"],
)

link(
    name = "TARGET_B",
    srcs = [],
    deps =  [
        "//:TARGET_A"
    ],
    includes = [
        "src",
        "TEST_LIB_SRC",
        "PTEST_CONFIG",

    ]
)
```

---

So far, he is what I have but it won't work

`rules.bzl`:

```
HCInfo = provider(

    doc = "Information about how to work with C dependencies.",
   
    fields = ["compiler_path", "archiver_path", "linker_path",
            "arch_flags", 
            "project_flags", "archives", "includes", "objects"],
)

# Object file
def object_file_impl(ctx):
    includes = _collect_headers(ctx)
    objs = _compile_sources(ctx, includes)

    return [
        DefaultInfo(
            files = depset(objs),
        ),
        HCInfo(
            includes = depset(ctx.files.includes, transitive = [dep[HCInfo].includes for dep in ctx.attr.deps]),
            objects = depset(objs, transitive = [dep[HCInfo].objects for dep in ctx.attr.deps]),
        ),
    ]

object_file = rule(
    _object_file_impl,
    attrs = {
        "includes": attr.label_list(
            allow_files = True,
            doc = "Public include directories for this object file",
        ),
        "srcs": attr.label_list(
            allow_files = [".c", ".h"],
            doc = "Source files to compile for this object file",
        ),
        "deps": attr.label_list(
            providers = [HCInfo],
            mandatory = False
        ),
    },
    
    doc = "Build an object file from C source code",
    toolchains = ["//ccppc_tools:toolchain_type"],
)
# Linking
def _link_impl(ctx):
    includes = _collect_headers(ctx)
    objs = depset(transitive = [dep[HCInfo].objects for dep in ctx.attr.deps]).to_list()


    executable = ctx.actions.declare_file(ctx.label.name)
    _ldppc_link(
        ctx,
        objs = objs,
        out = executable,
    )

    return [DefaultInfo(
                files = depset([executable])
            ),
            HCInfo(
                includes = depset(includes, transitive = [dep[HCInfo].includes for dep in ctx.attr.deps])
            )
    ]

link = rule(
    _link_impl,
    attrs = {
        "srcs": attr.label_list(
            allow_files = [".o"],
            doc = "Source files to link",
            mandatory = False,
        ),
        "includes": attr.label_list(
            allow_files = True,
        ),
        "deps": attr.label_list(
            providers = [HCInfo],
        ),
    },
    doc = "Link object files from C source code",
    toolchains = ["//ccppc_tools:toolchain_type"],
)
```

---

I tried to return HCInfo structure from the `link` rule but it didn't work

Comment: `link(name="TARGET_B")` depends on `object_file(name="TARGET_A")`, but you seem to be asking how to access attributed for the former from the latter, that doesn't sound right / won't fly as `TARGET_A` has no clue about `TARGET_B`. Is the problem looking at the relation from the wrong direction? Or have I misunderstood the question?